# JSF PrimeFaces inputText inside dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

*JSF-2.0, Mojarra 2.1.19, PrimeFaces 3.4.1*

***Summary of the problem**: Have a `p:inputText` inside `p:dataTable` and inputText action fired by `p:remoteCommand` which passes the dataTable row index as a parameter with `f:setPropertyActionListener`. But it always passes the last row of the dataTable, not the index of the row which includes currently clicked `p:inputText`.*

---

As it can be seen from my previous questions, I am trying to use `p:inputText` as a comment taker for a status like in Facebook or etc. Implementation includes a `p:dataTable`. It's rows represents each status. Seems like:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{statusBean.statusList}" var="status"
                     rowIndexVar="indexStatusList">
    <p:column>
        <p:panel id="statusRepeatPanel">
            <p:remoteCommand name="test" action="#{statusBean.insertComment}"
                update="statusRepeatPanel">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                    target="#{statusBean.indexStatusList}"
                    value="#{indexStatusList}">
                </f:setPropertyActionListener>
            </p:remoteCommand>
            <p:inputText id="commentInput" value="#{statusBean.newComment}"
                onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { test(); return false; }">
            </p:inputText>
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Upper code says when the press enter key, fire `p:remoteCommand` which calls the insert method of the managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StatusBean {
    List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();
    public int indexStatusList;
    public String newComment
    //getters and setters
    public void insertComment() {
        long statusID = findStatusID(statusList.get(indexStatusList));
        statusDao.insert(this.newComment,statusID)
    }
```

Let's debug together; assuming there are *three* statuses shown in the `p:dataTable`, click in the `p:inputText` which in the *second* status(index of 1), type "relax" and press the enter key.

In the debug console, it correctly shows "relax", but it finds the wrong status because `indexStatusList` has the value of 2 which belongs **the last status** in the `p:statusList`. It must be 1 which is the index of `p:inputText` that clicked on the dataTable row.

I think problem is about `p:remoteCommand` which takes the last index on the screen.

---

**How it works?**

Let's imagine there is a `p:commandLink` instead of `p:remoteCommand` and `p:inputText`:

```
<p:commandLink action=#{statusBean.insertComment>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{statusBean.indexStatusList}"
          value="#{indexStatusList}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
```

This component successfully passes the `indexStatusList` as currently clicked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptual problem in this solution lies in way how `p:remoteCommand` works. It creates JavaScript function whose name is defined in `name` attribute of `p:remoteCommand`. As you putted this in `dataTable` it will iterate and create JavaScript function called `test` as many times as there is rows in this table, and at the end last one will be only one. So, solution can be in appending index at the name of the `remoteCommand` but that is bad, because you will have many unnecessary JavaScript functions. Better approach would be to create one function an pass argument to it. So define `remoteCommand` outside of datatable:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="test" action="#{statusBean.insertComment}" update="statusRepeatPanel">
```

and call `test` function like this in your `onkeypress` event:

```js
test([{ name: 'rowNumber', value: #{indexStatusList} }])
```

This will pass `rowNumber` parameter in your AJAX request. In backing bean's `insertComment()` method you can read this parameter and do with it anything you want:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
Integer rowNumber = Integer.parseInt(map.get("rowNumber").toString());
```

NOTE: as you are updating panel in each row, maybe you can change `update` attribute of `remoteCommand` to `@parent` so this will work for all rows.

EDIT: You can update the specific panel in specific row with following code in Java method:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentinstance().update("form:dataTable:" + rowNumber + ":statusRepeatPanel")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I am going to review for update value after finishing the js function for update the view layer correctly.

Comment: dude is there any way to do update="form:dataTable:#{rowNumber}:statusRepeatPanel" in remoteCommand. Because I don't want to update whole form?

Comment: Try adding `RequestContext.getCurrentinstance().update("form:dataTable:" + rowNumber + ":statusRepeatPanel")` in server method after initialization of `rowNumber`.